# Angular UI doesn't update when change is made from ipcRenderer from electronjs

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, ipc

I have set up an electronjs app and use angular for the front end. At first I did it kinda wrong and used websockets for the communictaion between those two. The app was already finished but I wanted to do it the right way and switch to ipcRenderer for communication.

After changing everything something strange happend. The UI doesn't update anymore after a value was changed by an ipcRenderer call. For example, I have an html element that gets a class if `isInstalling` is set to `true`. When I change the value, the UI will change to. That did work with `ws` but now with ipcRenderer it won't work. The value will still be set but the UI just wont Update. `isInstalling` is set to `true` when the click event is fired and will be set to `false` when `onFinished` is called.

Here is my code:

preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRenderer", {
    onStep: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on("step", callback),
    onDownload: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on("download", callback),
    onFinished: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on("finished", callback),

    [...]
});
```

ipc.service.ts

```
export class IpcService {

  constructor() { }

  getIpcRenderer(){
    return (<any>window).ipcRenderer;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("INIT");
    
    this.ipcRenderer.onStep((event: any, text: string) => {
      this.addStep(text);
    });

    this.ipcRenderer.onDownload((event: any, data: any) => {
      this.progress = data.percent;
      this.current = data.current;
      this.total = data.total;
    });

    this.ipcRenderer.onFinished((event: any) => {
      console.log("Finished!!");
      this.isInstalling = false;
    });
  }

  addStep(step: string) {
    this.steps.push(step)
    this.steps = [...this.steps]; // Before, this will force an update of a displayed list that used *ngFor
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="{'disabledImage': isInstalling}" (click)="download()">
    <img style="margin: 0px;" width="400px" src="./assets/image.png">
</div>
```

So all the code did work in the past but not anymore. Also strange, the list that I displayed from `this.steps` wont display live changes, but when I fire the click event again, all the list items will be displayed. As if the click will update the UI and thats it.

So any Idea what I need to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses zone.js to detect changes, but by default it is not aware of electron's ipcRenderer. You can enable support by adding this to the end of polyfills.ts:

`import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-electron';`

Alternatively, you can manually trigger change detection in each callback:

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

//...

this.ipcRenderer.onFinished((event: any) => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => { // trigger zone change detection
    console.log("Finished!!");
    this.isInstalling = false;
  });
});
```

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md (electron section)

https://angular.io/guide/zone

Comment: Ah very nice! Do I need to install something for it to work via polyfills.ty? I added the line but it says `./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-patch-electron.js:40:28-110 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@electron/remote/dist/src/renderer/callbacks-registry' in 'D:\HDD\projects\myproject\node_modules\zone.js\dist'`

Comment: The warning is shown if you're using electron < v14, but the ipcRenderer change detection should still work.

Comment: It doesn't work. But that warning is telling me that the module can't be found so nothing can change if nothing new gets loaded I guess. And I am using electron v21.2.3

Comment: Does it work if you manually trigger change detection with `ngZone.run`?

Comment: Yeah that works. I will do it that way for now. Thank you :)